# Security risk analysis software

Tags: risk-management, risk-analysis

I am looking for some risk assessment tools (preferably open source), which make the analysis of a system based on its hardware structure given as input and point out potential weaknesses of this system. For example, given a WiFi access point in a system, I would expect from the analysis tool to warn about its potential risks and to suggest security measures against those risks.

Is there any such kind of software, for instance in the field of IT security, medicine, military service or any other?

Would be happy to hear some expert opinion.

Comment: [kali 2](https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-2-release-day-scheduled/)

Answer (score 2):

As far as tools themselves go, they're too many to count. They're new tools that are being made every day that a simple google search  of what you're testing should suffice. Needless to say, people have collected these tools into operating systems for use.

Here is a list of a few:

**[Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/)**
Kali linux is probably the most popular as it gains it's roots from Backtrack and it has the ability to be deployed to the raspberry pi , android phones and many other platforms.

**[BackBox](https://www.backbox.org/)**
Backbox is very similar, while it may be considered more stable, it's doesn't have as much support as Kali and cannot be deployed to the wide range of systems that Kali can.

Here is a list of others you can try out: [10 of the best Linux distros for privacy fiends and security buffs](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/security-software/10-of-the-best-linux-distros-for-privacy-fiends-and-security-buffs-1292902)

Now, keep in mind that these are simply glorified linux systems with a collection of tools for a task. You can grab a linux Mint distro and get all the tools you want, install them and be on your way to working on a project.

Also, I am adding [this](http://remnux.org) because it's not listed.

Remnux is for malware analysis and was made by Lenny Zeltzer. It is a great OS/environment for working and performing diagnostics on malware. To name a few it can be used as a gateway to provide false replies to malware and interact with it.